# How to create Sunburst with children spanning through multiple parents using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to create a D3 Sunburst that may be having the same children spanning through multiple parents.

Eg: Need to plot some events under weeks. In some cases, events can span multiple weeks, say Event-1 start from week 3 and ends on 4. How can it be done?

Also, is it possible to plot the Sunburst in the opposite way, parents at the outer ring and children inside?